# Image View Not Showing on Today View Extension

Tags: ios, uiimageview, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I am trying to display an image view in my today view extension but it doesn't appear. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you're re-using an image from your main project, make sure it's being copied in the "Copy Bundle Resources" part of your Widget project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the image is not appearing. The problem is that *nothing* is appearing. The reason is that you have not used internal constraints to size your widget, so your widget has no size. (In theory you can size your widget with `preferredContentSize`, but I have not found this to be reliable.)